# Aligning list items of a HorizontalListView

Tags: android

The items in my horizontallistview are appearing from right side of the device screen when I start my application. But whenever an item is added to the listview at run time it get aligned to the left side of the screen. How shall I modify my code to make my list view to appear from right side of the screen from first itself.
Hereby, I'm attaching the code of my custom listview item.

//horizontal list view code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.example.app.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/hlistview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is horizontallistview code?

Comment: Thanks for an early reply. Now I've attached the code of horizontal listview too.

Comment: List gets populated from right end of the screen. I want it to start populating from left end of the screen

Comment: set listview layoutgravity.

Comment: That doesn't help me. Initially the listview consist of single item and it gets aligned to left of the screen when I run the app but when I add items to the listview at run time it get populated with new data and appears from right side of the screen

Comment: I want the listview to appear from right from application launch itself.